# HTML link inside Table Angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using Angular js ;
inside my view template I have a Table 
I want each row of my table which is populated by an element from my model to be a link to another page.
I tried the commented line of code but it does not work!

Thanks for Your help!
Cheers!

```
<section data-ng-controller="AllsController" data-ng-init="find()">
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Alls</h1>
</div>

<div class="list-group">

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Created</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Color</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="all in alls">
                <!-- <a data-ng-href="#!/alls/{{all._id}}" > -->

                <td data-ng-bind="all.created | date:'medium'"></td>
                <td data-ng-bind="all.user.displayName"></td>
                <td data-ng-bind="all.name"></td>
                <td data-ng-bind="all.color"></td>

                <!-- </a> -->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot wrap the `<td>` elements like that. You can try add an `ngClick` or `ngHref` handler to the `<tr>` but that may not work either. If not, just add the click/href handler to each `<td>` element. My guess is that `ngHref` wouldn't work either, so you'll probably have to handle the click within your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like
`<tr ng-click="onClick()">` and in your onClick function you can write your logic. If you want to redirect to some page you can use $location service of angularjs.

Comment: I wouldn't use `document.location` on a `onclick` if I am using angular